# Android Firebase language eror

Tags: android, firebase

I have an online quiz app.Firebase related app.If my phone is in English, the app works fine, but when it change into Turkish, the app is instantaneous crash.Please help me

Comment: Are you using Firebase UI in your project?

Comment: Yes why this peoblem happend?

Comment: It is recommended you post you log messages here.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Can you please update your post with your code?

Answer (score 1):

I searched it a little bit and I found the [following](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android):

> As of version 2.1.0 FirebaseUI includes translations for all string resources. In order to ensure that you only get the translations relevant to your application, we recommend changing the resConfigs of your application module

You can change it simply **by adding the following code** to the application-level gradle file (If you add this, only english will be displayed in your app)

```
android {
    // ...

    defaultConfig {
       // ...
       resConfigs "en" // And any other languages you support
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked it out, but still had the same problem